# In the Matrix is there any indication in films or novelization that time travel is possible?

Tags: time-travel, the-matrix

It seems to me that even in the Matrix, paradoxes would still occur that might prevent time travel or that other aspects of the Matrix that are there to faithfully duplicate "the real world" might. Has time travel been discussed?

Comment: If there's one thing The Matrix needs, it's more complicated universe mechanics.

Comment: future-works might apply here since there is a new film dropping that...as Paul states...

Comment: @NKCampbell - Future works doesn't apply here since OP is asking about the films, etc that have been released thus far.

Answer (score 5):

There is, as yet, no hint that time travel exists within the universe of *The Matrix* (the four films), nor is it mentioned or used in any of the Animatrix stories, web comics or supplementary artbooks or scriptbooks.

Additionally, if anyone (human or machine) had ready access to time travel technology, there's no good reason for them not to have used it [as a weapon](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Time_travel), for example, to prevent Smith's takeover of the Matrix or the rise of the "singular consciousness" that caused the downfall of humanity.

Comment: Without knowing how the time travel would even work in The Matrix universe, I don't know if it's safe to say "there's no good reason" for them not to have used it as a weapon.  If it was written as a causal time loop with no alternate timelines or anything; I'm sure you could come up with a lot of time travel plots that explain why it was never able to be used as a weapon (e.g. everyone who attempted it actually caused The Matrix in the first place).  You can come up with a lot of "good reasons" when you add time travel in the mix.  The first paragraph seems like more than enough reason.

Comment: @JMac - There's zero indication it exists. If it existed, one or both side would have tried to use it. Now you need to invent additional reasons why they didn't use it

Comment: My point was more than when you introduce time travel, you can make some _really_ convoluted plots.  There's nothing really stopping someone from making a prequel story about how they _did_ use time travel; but because of a series of events all that it was able to do was actually put the events in motion that led to The Matrix, for example.  Like you say, there's no indication that it exists; but because it's a fictional story, if the people in charge wanted to, they could always add it in and still leave it self-consistent with the existing plots.

Comment: So my point is that although you say "there's no good reason not to use it", a time travel plot could easily incorporate them already using the technology; and come up with it's own reasons why we don't notice it in any of the other Matrix media.  It would almost definitely be terrible writing; but it could be done.

Comment: Regarding your side comment, I assumed the question was asking about time travel *within the Matrix*, which would be under the control of the machines and not weaponizable. (except perhaps against Smith and other free agents)

Comment: @Z.Cochrane - Ah well, now the machines use a mixture of memory control and "deja vu" small changes to control the surroundings. Whether that qualifies as 'time travel' is sorta kinda debatable.

Comment: If a human created a concept of time travel within the matrix then it would not be real, nothing invented or created in the matrix is real, the matrix decided if something is allowed to happen. Therefore there is no possible way a human could invent a time machine in the matrix that would actually work. The matrix could present the idea of time travel by creating a new vr environment that looks like the past and then make the human think that they had returned to the future. But more likely, the Matrix just makes the time machine not work, and probably blows it up to stop future work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you define time travel in the matrix universe.

The Earth in reality is in the future but the Matrix always remains in the 20th Century so from the point of view of those locked in the matrix if they escape they have traveled to the future.

Within the Matrix anything is possible, so someone could "create a Time machine" which in reality just allows them to exist in there own matrix that looks like the past.

Outside of the Matrix, it is unlikely that Humanity has either the capacity or the technology to investigate and make Time Travel work, they are struggling just to survive. In addition Humanity is periodically wiped out by the machines so it is unlikely the amount of knowledge would be gathered to allow a breakthrough like Time travel.

In terms of the Machines, it seems unlikely they would have a desire to investigate the idea of time travel, there would be little to gain for them.

Now the real question, what happens if the someone in the matrix is able to create there own matrix. What if the whole of the Matrix (machines and Humans) is a VR inside a VR?